# Find the general solution of the equation: $xu_{xx} + u_{xy}=0$.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations

Find the general solution of the equation: $xu_{xx} + u_{xy}=0$, $u = u(x,y)$.
I used canonical form to solve it and we know it's hyperbolic. I set $\mu (x,y) = xe^{-y}$ and $\eta (x,y)= y$. Then solve it and I finally get $u_{\mu} = u_{\mu \eta}$, which gives me $u = u_{\eta} + F(\eta)$.
I don't know how to proceed from here. I tried different $\mu$, but still got the same $u_{\mu} = u_{\mu \eta}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $F(\eta)$ is arbitrary, we can replace it with $-e^{\eta}G'(\eta)$.  Your equation becomes $u_\eta-u=e^{\eta}G'(\eta)$.  Multiplying by $e^{-\eta}$: $\partial_\eta(e^{-\eta}u)=G'(\eta)$, so $u(\eta,\mu)=e^{\eta}H(\mu)+e^{\eta}G(\eta)$, which we can rewrite as $u(\eta,\mu)=K(\eta)+e^{\eta}H(\mu)$, where $K$ and $H$ are arbitrary functions.

Comment: How did you come up with $-e^{\eta}G'(\eta)$? I think that's the key part.

Comment: @Fei By inspection, mostly.  Your equation is $$u_\eta-u=-F(\eta)$$, so $$\partial_\eta(e^{-\eta}u)=-e^{-\eta}F(\eta)$$.  Therefore, $$e^{-\eta}u(\eta,\mu)=u(0,\mu)-\int_0^\eta e^{-\xi}F(\xi)d\xi$$, where $u(0,\mu):=H(\mu)$ is arbitrary.  Inspecting the integral shows that putting $F(\xi)=-e^{\xi}G'(\xi)$ gives the desired simplification.